# Serverless/Lambda + S3: Is it possible to catch a 'GetObject' event and select a different resource?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

What I'm trying to do is catch any image file request and check if that image doesn't exists, return a different image.

I'm taking a look at Lambda and the Serverless Framework, but I couldn't find much information about this. Is it even possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no GetObject event. Please, follow this [link](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/NotificationHowTo.html#supported-notification-event-types) for a list of supported events. S3 will only notify you (or trigger a Lambda function) when an object is created, removed or lost due to reduced redundancy.

So, it's not possible to do exactly what you want, but you have a few alternatives.

#### Alternatives

1. Use [Lambda@Edge](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-edge.html) to intercept your calls to a CloudFront distribution that uses a S3 as Origin. This interceptor could be able to send another file if the requested one is missing. This is not a good solution since you would increase latency and costs to your operation.
2. Instead of offering a S3 endpoint to your clients, offer a API Gateway endpoint. In this case, ALL image requests would be processed by a Lambda function with the possibility to give another file if the requested one is missing. This is not a good solution since you would increase latency and costs to your operation.
3. And the **best option**, that may work, but I have not tried, is to configure a S3 bucket Redirection Rule. This is a common use case for static website hosting where a page not found (status code 404) redirects to another page (like page-not-found.html). In your case, you could try to redirect to an address of a default image. This solution would not use Lambda functions.

Comment: *"You could indeed create a S3 event to trigger a Lambda function on GetObjects"* Events are for object creation and deletion.  There is no `GetObject` event in S3.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot, thanks for correcting me! I've updated my answer. I thought that you could create S3 notifications for any kind of S3 operations, but in fact the list of event types is very restricted.

Comment: S3 events allow you to hook anything that *changes* the bucket.  That is their purpose.  Also, you might also test your theory with Lambda@Edge.  I tested early on in the preview and found that origin errors don't trigger the Lambda response functions.  I worked around that with L@E *plus* an S3 redirect rule and then rewrote the `Location:` header from S3, using regex logic in Lambda to allow more flexible rewriting than S3 allows... but L@E can only do limited content substitution -- the L@E environment is more restrictive than ordinary Lambda -- no network access, no temp space, or AWS SDK.